# Pydantic: How to type hint a model constructor?

Tags: type-hinting, pydantic

How to properly type hint a model constructor, e.g. function that takes a model class and returns a model instance?

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Point(BaseModel):
    x: int
    y: int
```

First approach:

```py
def make_model_instance(model: type[BaseModel], **kwargs) -> BaseModel:
    return model(**kwargs)

point: Point = make_model_instance(model=Point, x=1, y=2)
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here the linter flags the call to make_model_instance, but only if I type hint `point` with `Point`.

Second approach:

```py
from typing import TypeVar

ModelType = TypeVar("ModelType", bound=BaseModel)

def make_model_instance(model: ModelType, **kwargs) -> ModelType:
    return model(**kwargs)
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~


point: Point = make_model_instance(model=Point, x=1, y=2)
                                         ^~~~~
```

Third approach:

```py
from typing import TypeVar

ModelType = TypeVar("ModelType", bound=BaseModel)

def make_model_instance(model: type[ModelType], **kwargs) -> ModelType:
    return model(**kwargs)


point: Point = make_model_instance(model=Point, x=1, y=2)
```

This appears to do the trick, no complaints from the linter, but I don't really know why.

Comment: Your third approach is correct. In first snippet you forget everything about the type, it's only BaseModel when returned from the "constructor", not a specific subclass. Second snippet is plain wrong: you hint to to take an instance as a first argument, not a class. Finally, the third one is fine: you ask for type of some model (`type[BaseModel]`) and return an instance of **the same type**.

Comment: @STerliakov thanks for your reply. Could you maybe explain the problem with the second approach a bit further? I think it has something to do with the fact that `type[BaseModel]` actually means BaseModel's metaclass and `BaseModel` as a return type is also incorrect because `BaseModel` can't be instantiated directly. I don't know if the latter is enforced by a static type checker though, I think the exception for instantiation of a BaseModel is raised dynamically.

Comment: Forget BaseModel, imagine `T = TypeVar('T', bound=int)`. `def f(x: T) -> T: return x` is correct and can be called as `f(0)`. Cf. `def g(x: type[T]) -> T): return x()` - it's to be called as `g(int)` to return 0. Whenever you hint a variable as T (where T is a class), it means "instance of class T or any subclass of it". `type[T]` means "instance of (type of type of T)", so "class T itself, or any subclass of T". There's a hidden trick: not any class with T's metaclass, but really T or subclass of T only. I'll write an answer later today, it's hard to explain "type vs class" in one comment.